# vba loop until boolean is false - userform button

Tags: excel, vba, loops, boolean, userform

I want to execute a sub over and over again while a button is set true.
My first idea would be a while or do while loop but I cant quite figure out how its done properly. In my case Excel just stops running.

A Userform Button sets the boolean "status" true or false when pressed. If the "status" is true the sub should be executed in a loop. The sub itself triggers a calculation which adds an amount of money to the double "bank". If the same button is pressed again the loop should end.

```
Function aktivate(i As Integer)
    array(i).status = True
    call myLoop(i)
End Function


Function deaktivate(i As Integer)
    array(i).status = False
End Function


Function myLoop(i As Integer)
    Do While array(i).status = True
        Call calc(i)

        If array(i).status = False Then Exit Do
    Loop
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `DoEvents` inside the `Do While` loop so that you can press the "Stop" button. If you don't then the code will become unresponsive and crash excel.

See this example

```
Dim stopLoop As Boolean

Sub StartCode()
    stopLoop = False
    LoopCode
End Sub

Sub StopCode()
    stopLoop = True
End Sub

Sub LoopCode()
    Do While stopLoop = False
        Debug.Print "blah"
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: that seems to do the trick, thanks a lot for the quick answer!